# The proofs for every convergence subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have seen two proofs for

> If $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers and if its every convergent subsequence converges to the same value $L$, then $\{x_n\}$ also converges to the same value.

I have one question about each of the proofs.

### First proof

This is the sketch of the first proof.

> Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ does not converge to $L$. Then there is an
>   $\epsilon>0$ such that for every positive integer $N$ there is a postive integer $n\geq N$ with $|x_n-L|\geq\epsilon$. We form inductively a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ such that $|x_{n_k}-L|\geq\epsilon$. Since $\{x_{n_k}\}$ is bounded, there is a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_{k_j}}\}_{j=1}^\infty$. This subsequence itself is a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ and by the hypothesis $\{x_{n_{k_j}}\}_{j=1}^\infty$ is convergent but $|x_{n_{k_j}}-L|\geq\epsilon$ and so $\{x_{n_{k_j}}\}_{j=1}^\infty$ does not converge to $L$. Contradiction.

My question is why did we need to form the subsequence $\{x_{n_{k_j}}\}_{j=1}^\infty$? in other words, what is wrong with this shorter proof

> Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ does not converge to  $L$. Then there is an
>   $\epsilon>0$ such that for every positive integer $N$ there is a postive integer $n\geq N$ with $|x_n-L|\geq\epsilon$. We form inductively a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ such that $|x_{n_k}-L|\geq\epsilon$. Since $\{x_n\}$ is bounded, there is a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_j}\}$ but $|x_{n_{j}}-L|\geq\epsilon$ and so $\{x_{n_j}\}$ does not converge to $L$. contradiction.

### Second Proof

The following proof is taken from [this document](http://homepages.umflint.edu/~bgerics/Analysis%20problem%20set.pdf).

> [image]

Is this proof correct? the proof says each mentioned interval contain ***all but a finite number of elements***.

Comment: I think that in the first line of the first proof "to any $L$" must be replaced by something like: "to the common limit $L$ of the convergent subsequences". Then you find inductively a convergent subsequence that does *not* converge to $L$ and a contradiction is found.

Comment: @drhab: Thanks. I fixed it.

Comment: Sorry, but should focus on a subsequence of $(x_{n_k})_k$ (wich is also a subsequence of $(x_n)_n$ of course). This to make sure that it cannot have $L$ as limit. That's what they did in the longer (and correct) proof.

Comment: The statement, as given, "If every convergent subsequence converges to the same limit, L, then the sequence converges to L", is not true!  It should be "If every subsequence converges **and** converges to the same limit, L, then the sequence converge to L".  I suspect that was what you meant but your wording, "every **convergent** subsequence**" leaves the possibility that some subsequences do not convege.

Comment: @user247327  I disagree. It is true and it is not necessary mention the **necessary** condition that all subsequences converge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ is constructed that cannot possibly have any subsequences that converge to $L$.

This sequence has a convergent subsequence (since it is a bounded sequence), and we conclude that this convergent subsequence must have a limit different from $L$. This convergent subsequence is also a subsequence of the original sequence, so a contradiction is found.

In your shorter "proof" you also construct sequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ but you do not really make use of it. It seems that you just leave it aside and step back to the original sequence $(x_n)_n$ and its subsequences.

The second proof works under **assumption** that the original sequence is convergent and shows that it cannot have a limit that differs from $L$. But what you are after is a **proof** of this assumption.